# AS3 - Using struct information to decompress a format

Tags: actionscript-3, struct, byte, compression

I'm wondering, is it possible to use [this](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=BLB) sort of information in AS3 to decompress a format? I've seen people use C++ to decompress similar formats, but since I'm fluent in AS3 I'd like to know if I can use my ActionScript knowledge to do the same.

It might be obvious but I haven't worked much with ByteArrays and am pretty inexperienced with manipulating bytes. I'm willing to learn though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using [`IDataInput`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IDataInput.html) methods--you can read from a FileStream or Socket directly, or you can process a ByteArray.  Adobe has [an example for ZIP files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d53.html), which is essentially the same as your use case.  You do need to know how many bytes each member of the struct takes up (i.e., DWORD is usually 32 bits unsigned).

For your example:

```
struct BLBHeader                    class Header 
{                                   {    
    char    szID[4];                    public var szID:ByteArray;
    BYTE    bID;                        public var bID:uint;
    BYTE    bUnknown;                   public var bUnknwon:uint;
    WORD    wDataSize;                  public var wDataSize:uint;
    DWORD dwFileSize;                   public var dwFileSize:uint;
    DWORD dwNumber;                     public var dwNumber:uint;
};                                  }

function readHeader(input:IDataInput):Header {
    var header:Header = new Header();

    // ByteArrays have to be pre-allocated
    header.szID      = new ByteArray();
    input.readBytes(header.szID, 0, 4);

    // primitives just get read in
    header.bID       = input.readUnsignedByte();  // 8 bits
    header.bUnknown  = input.readUnsignedByte();
    header.wDataSize = input.readUnsignedShort(); // 16 bits
    DWORD dwFileSize = input.readUnsignedInt();   // 32 bits
    DWORD dwNumber   = input.readUnsignedInt(); 
};
```

If you wanted szID to be a String instead, you could use

```
header.szID = input.readMultiByte(4, 'us-ascii'); // one byte per char
```

To use:

```
var header:Header = readHeader(input);
var fileIDs:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 0; i < header.dwNumber; ++i) {
    fileIDs.push( readFileID(input) );
}
... // continue with readDirEntry(input), readDataSection(input), ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks just like what I need. Thing is, I have no experience in doing this sort of thing in any language, and although I think I understand some parts, I'm a bit confused with others. If you'd happen to know a tutorial that sort of outlines about reading bytes in general (and stuff like signed/unsigned, little/big endian, etc), that would probably help me. Also, how does the IDataInput know what to read? Does it store the current offset position or something?

Comment: How IDataInput works depends on the implementation--ByteArray uses an offset, FileStream a consumable stream.

Comment: Well, I found a guide which explains manipulating and using bytes a bit more, so I think your answer is enough to get me started. In any case you answered my question, so I've now marked it as accepted :)